# How to pass a constant pointer to a method in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I've this constructor of a Node class:

```
Node::Node(int item,  Node const * next)
{
    this->item = item;
    this->next = next;
}
```

When I compile it gives a compile error: invalid conversion from 'const Node*' to 'Node*'

Is there a way to pass a pointer pointing to constant data?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, but the compiler is right to complain: you're assigning a "pointer to a const `Node`" to a variable with a type of "pointer to a non-const `Node`".  If you later modify `this->next`, you're violating the contract of "I will not modify the variable pointed to by `next`.

The easy fix is just to declare `next` as a pointer to non-const data.  If the variable `this->next` will truly never be modified for the life of the `Node` object, then you can alternatively declare the class member to be a pointer to a `const` object:

```
class Node
{
    ...
    const Node *next;
}:
```

Also note the distinction between "pointer to `const` data" and "`const` pointer to data".  For single-level pointers, there are 4 types of pointers in regards to their `const`ness:

```
Node *ptr;  // Non-constant pointer to non-constant data
Node *const ptr;  // Constant pointer to non-constant data
const Node *ptr;  // Non-constant pointer to constant data
Node const *ptr;  // Same as above
const Node *const ptr;  // Constant pointer to constant data
Node const *const ptr;  // Same as above
```

Note that `const Node` is the same as `Node const` at the last level, but the placement of `const` with regards to the pointer declaration ("`*`") is very important.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass a pointer pointing to constant data?

Yes. Use `Node const*` (or `const Node*`) as you have showed in your code.

To fix your compiler error, you have 3 choices:

1. `Node::Node()` should receive a non-const pointer so that
   it can be assigned to `this->next`
2. Change the design and declare `Node::next` also a `Node const*`
3. Typecast, `this->next = const_cast<Node*>(next);`

The 3rd solution should be used with utmost care otherwise it may result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
It also works with pointers but one has to be careful where ‘const’ is put as that determines whether the pointer or what it points to is constant. For example,

    const int * Constant2
declares that Constant2 is a variable pointer to a constant integer and

    int const * Constant2
is an alternative syntax which does the same, whereas

    int * const Constant3
declares that Constant3 is constant pointer to a variable integer and

    int const * const Constant4
declares that Constant4 is constant pointer to a constant integer. Basically ‘const’ applies to whatever is on its immediate left (other than if there is nothing there in which case it applies to whatever is its immediate right).
```

http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html   I think this link will help you.you need know what `const` mean.Good Luck.